# Add a row to RoR database that references other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table Owners, and Pets. Each Owner has_many pets, and each pet belong_to owner. I'm writing a function that creates a new pet by taking in the owner_id and the pet information. So far I have

```
pet = Pet.new(pet_hash)
pet.save
```

But how do I associate that Pet with the owner_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the owner, you can do something like:

```
owner.pets.build(pet_hash)
owner.save
```